# How to customize publish area in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, filter, action

I want to add a text message in "publish" area in admin panel.
Are there any filters or actions to edit?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

such as

```
add_atction('in_admin_footer', 'blahblah');
function blahblah($content) {
    $content .= '<strong> Please make sure you input correct data</strong>';
    return $content;
}
```

The 'in_admin_footer' action helps to add a message to the real footer of admin panel.
I want to Publish area.

http://gyazo.com/8342ffb94ae1a829988257bf2506c3d6

(string(0) "" is addded by in_admin_footer action)

Comment: text message ? please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `post_submitbox_misc_actions` action hook. Something along these lines:

```
function submitbox_callback() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') { //if you only want to display this on posts
      echo '<strong> Please make sure you input correct data</strong>';
    }
}
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'submitbox_callback' );
```